# Нужно вывести данные которые не находятся в промежутке между 5000 и 10000

Tags: mysql, sql

Думал что так, но не работает:

```
select first_name, last_name, salary 
from employees
where salary<5000 AND salary>10000
order by employee_id
```

Может через `between` или `AND` заменить на `OR`?

Comment: select first_name, last_name, salary from employees where   salary < 5000  or salary >10000 order by employee_id

забыл там поставить OR. сам нашел)))))

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, но мне НЕНУЖЕН промежуток который находится в интервале

Comment: Ой, да, я проглядел «не»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `NOT BETWEEN`:

```
select first_name, last_name, salary 
from employees where salary NOT BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
order by employee_id
```

Comment: да, тоже вариант. спасибо)

Comment: раз ответ вам помог :) то: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: хорошо, сейчас .